# Remove numbers and spaces from beginning of strings in array

Tags: bash

I read in file entries into an array like this:

```
readarray files < $MY_DIR/file_list.cfg
```

`file_list.cfg` could look like this:

```
1  file1.cfg
2   some_other_file.cfg
3  yet_another_file_name
```

How do I remove any numbers and spaces before the actual file names in bash. I would like to modify the array after it has been read rather than filtering the content while populating the array.

Comment: Any reason why you don't want this to be done at time of populating the array. It seems to be sane reason anyway

Comment: The array is used in quite a few places throughout the script and i would like to copy the array and filter out the data i need in the copy to not affect any other user of the array data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After populating your array (use the `-t` switch to remove trailing newline, and use lower case variable names):

```
mapfile -t files < "$my_dir/file_list.cfg"
```

you can use parameter expansions:

```
files_clean=( "${files[@]##+([[:digit:][:space:]])}" )
```

This assumes that you have the `extglob` shell option on. Use

```
shopt -s extglob
```

to turn it on.